# How to use no-data-to-display within Highcharts-Vue wrapper

Tags: vue.js, highcharts

I'm making use of `highcharts-vue`. The wrapper works great but I can't figure out how to make use of the `no-data-to-display` module. My `main.js` looks basically like this:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App";
import BootstrapVue from "bootstrap-vue";
import HighchartsVue from 'highcharts-vue'
import globalFunc from "./mixins/mixins.js";
import { store } from "./store/store";
import axios from "axios";
import { router } from "./router/router.js";

Vue.prototype.$http = axios;
Vue.mixin(globalFunc);
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.use(HighchartsVue);

new Vue({
    store: store,
    router: router,
    el: "#app",
    render: h => h(App)
});
```

I asumed that the `noData` option would automatically be involved with use of `Vue.use(HighchartsVue)`, but that doesn't seem te be right.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [README](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue#importing-highcharts-modules) document, you also have to import `highcharts` itself:

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsNoData from 'highcharts-no-data-to-display';

HighchartsNoData(Highcharts);
```